# Наследование, обращение к полям производного класса c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Такая проблема, пусть у меня есть базовый класс со своими переменными x, y и производный класс с переменными x1, y1, x2, y2(x1, y1 ссылаются на x, y). Не могу понять, как обратиться к x1, y1, не создавая новых полей x1, y1 в производном классе? Они же ведь создаются в базовом классе, если я правильно понимаю. Код:

```
abstract class Figure
    {
        public int x, y;

        public Figure(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
}
class Rectangle : Figure
    {
        int x2, y2;

        public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : base(x1, y1)
        {
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }
}
```

Comment: У вас в базовом классе есть только `x` и `y`, именно туда и запишутся ваши `x1` и `y1`, и обращаться к ним нужно будет через `rectangle.x` и `rectangle.y`. Конструкция `base(x1, y1)` вызовет конструктор базового класса с двумя параметрами, передав туда `x1` и `y1`, а именно `public Figure(int x, int y)`. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться надо через `this.x` и `this.y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rectangle : Figure
{
  public int x2, y2;

  public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : base(x1, y1)
  {
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  public int x1 { get => x; set => x = value; }    
  public int y1 { get => y; set => y = value; }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю еще вариант, я так понял вас именно это интересует

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle a = new Rectangle(1,2,3,4);
            Console.WriteLine(a.GetX1());//1
        }

        abstract class Figure
        {
            public int x, y;

            public Figure(int x, int y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }
        class Rectangle : Figure
        {
            int x2, y2;

            public Rectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) : base(x1, y1)
            {
                this.x2 = x2;
                this.y2 = y2;
            }
            // Получает x базового класса
            public int GetX1(){
                return base.x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, я немного о другом. Вот допустим я хочу создать метод(пусть метод Рисовать()). Для работы метода мне нужны данные x1,y1,x2,y2. С x2, y2 ясно. Они инициализируются в классе Прямоугольника, все в порядке. Не в порядке только с x1, y1. Как мне к ним обратиться при работе с методом Рисовать(), не создавая новые public int x1, y1, как это произошло с x2, y2?

Comment: @ОлегФедоров как вариант перегрузить метод с другим количеством операторов. Но я щас напишу как бы сам сделал

Comment: я б [так](https://rextester.com/IIBY92551) сделал

Comment: я сам бы так сделал, но что делать, если такой случай с наследованием переменных снова повторится? Не хотелось бы перезадавать вопрос. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: @ОлегФедоров что-то я не понял, что именно повториться?

Comment: ситуация с наследованием полей классов.

Comment: @ОлегФедоров пример можете превести, а то что то не понятно мне )